# futex_wake() in gomp_barrier_wait_end() in the case of multiple waiters

Tags: futex, libgomp

I am trying to understand the use of `futex_wake()`, as called from [`gomp_barrier_wait_end()`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libgomp/config/linux/bar.c#L35), when invoked from [`gomp_team_start()`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libgomp/team.c#L319) (through [`gomp_barrier_wait()`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libgomp/config/linux/bar.c#L54)).

I see that `futex_wake()` is called in `gomp_barrier_wait_end()` only once. However, as I understand, it is possible that there are multiple waiters waiting on the supplied futex word. The [`futex` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/futex.2.html), as I read it, indicates that a `FUTEX_WAKE` may not wake up all of the waiting threads.

> FUTEX_WAKE (since Linux 2.6.0)
>
> This operation wakes ***at most*** [emphasis added] val of the waiters that are waiting
> (e.g., inside FUTEX_WAIT) on the futex word at the address uaddr.

Since the `FUTEX_WAKE` in `gomp_barrier_wait_end()` may not wake up all of the waiters, it seems to me that one or more subsequent `FUTEX_WAKE` invocations may be needed to wake the remaining waiters. However, looking at the call stack leading up to the `FUTEX_WAKE` in `gomp_barrier_wait_end()` from `gomp_team_start()`, I do not see any enclosing loop that would provide for the case where some threads are still waiting after the first `FUTEX_WAKE`.

Am I misunderstanding the `futex()` man page's section on `FUTEX_WAKE`? Or, is there some other mechanism in `libgomp` that will guarantee that all the waiters are woken up?

Update - [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78181666/3302997) from [David Schwartz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/721269/david-schwartz) made me realize that I did not ask the right question above.

The question I should have asked was, does FUTEX_WAKE make a guarantee that it will wake up some minimum number of waiters?

Answer (score 1):

Saying the operation wakes "at most" `val` waiters means two things:

1. It's not guaranteed not to wake fewer than `val` waiters.
2. It will not wake more than `val` waiters.

You probably don't think 2 is a problem. But 1 very obviously isn't a problem either.

It would be impossible for `FUTEX_WAKE` to guarantee not to wake fewer than `val` waiters. There might not even be that many waiters. So this lack of guarantee is not at all unexpected.

So neither of the things that "at most" clause is saying are an issue for the code.

Answer (score 0):

The futex man page says,

> ```
>    FUTEX_WAIT (since Linux 2.6.0)
>
>           This operation tests that the value at the futex word
>           pointed to by the address uaddr still contains the
>           expected value val, and if so, then sleeps waiting for a
>           FUTEX_WAKE operation on the futex word.
> ```

I believe that a reasonable interpretation of this statement, in combination with the `FUTEX_WAKE` section (quoted in the original question), is that all waiters on futex word `X` will be woken up on the next `FUTEX_WAKE` invocation for `X`, unless the next `FUTEX_WAKE` invocation for `X` is made with a `val` argument that is less than the number of waiters.